# Target Internal Link Of Another Page On Website

Tags: themes, navigation

In the `Edit Menus` page, you can select an internal page to link, or an external page.

I am building a giant single page where the hyperlinks target internal page headings, for example I have one of my menu elements set to `#one` that targets `<a name="one"></a>`on my homepage.

This is all ok whilst the user is on the giant single page. However I will have the last link to the blog. When on the blog I want the user still to be able to click these hyperlinks in the navigation.

I need a way of programming into the menu the following:

```
internal page id=x #one
```

If that makes sense? The link has to go to the giant single page and target the section.

In pure html this is what I am looking for:

```
<a href="www.mywebsite.com/giant-single-page#one">
```

The most obvious answer is for me to program these absolute links in, but I'd rather not do this. Is there a way to combine the internal links in the menu with section names?

I have full control of the theme and I can program, so please present to me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial and error I found the solution.
It's far simpler than I thought.

For example, because my page is the homepage, I use this as my link in the menu:

```
/#one
```

As opposed to:

```
#one
```

And it works. It doesn't matter what page I am on, once I click that link it takes me to the correct page and then to the correct section.

If you want to target the section of another page, just do the following:

```
/?page_id=21#four
```

Of course, this doesn't let you have the flexibility of selecting the page name in the menu customisation page, so you have to know the pages ID for this to work.